# Linux shell scripting error with while loop syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
initial="/"
usrname=`cut -d ":" -f1 users.txt`
password=`cut -d '"' -f3 users.txt|cut -d ":" -f2`
comment=`cut -d '"' -f2,3 users.txt|cut -d ":" -f1`
path=`cut -d "/" -f2,3 users.txt`
totalpath="$initial$path"
while read line
  do
  useradd -p "$password" -c "$comment" -m -d "$totalpath" "$usrname"
done < "users.txt"
```

I am  trying to add multiple users using text file. I am getting "syntax error near unexpected token `done'".
All my stored variables are coming out perfectly. I tested it using echo command. However, when I run the loop, the error message pops up and users are not getting created.

For your reference this is how my text file looks like:

```
acdeng:"ADLER CHARLES DAVID",00-9388,x0753,Engineering:acc944:/home/Engineering
ardsal:"ANSELL ROBERT D",14-2675,x1624,Sales:acc944:/home/Sales
```

Comment: Apart from any syntax error(s), the values of `$password`, `$comment` et al aren't going to be updated each time through the `while` loop; only `$line` is updated, and you don't use its value.

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste your *exact* code? I don't believe there's a syntax error in the code you posted (though there are some serious logical errors).

Comment: i am new to scripting. yes i copied the exact code.

Answer (score 2):

As pasted above, the script seems to run for me without any syntax error.

However, I'll note that you don't seem to be parsing each line of the file. The initial assignments to `usrname` et al are extracting multi-line slices, which you then use as-is on each iteration of the loop. You never refer to `$line` in the loop, so on each iteration you'll get the same call to `useradd`.

I recommend adding `echo` in front of `useradd` so you can see what commands you are actually emitting.

Comment: Hi dan,echo has no effect. Still the same error message. its not creating any users.

Comment: For you reference this is how my users.txt file looks like                      

acdeng:"ADLER CHARLES DAVID",00-9388,x0753,Engineering:acc944:/home/Engineering
ardsal:"ANSELL ROBERT D",14-2675,x1624,Sales:acc944:/home/Sales
bcmar:"BIANCHI CHRISTOPHER",12-2275,x3280,Marketing:acc944:/home/Marketing
cmbman:"CAPOZZI MICHAEL B",08-3191,x8035,Manufacturing:acc944:/home/Manufacturing

Comment: Danfuzz' middle paragraph is very important. Your "cut" invocations are outside your loop. You are reading the file once for each "cut" and then once in the loop.